# Using Spree's Devise for confirmation email, and connect via facebook and google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree, devise-confirmable

I have a spree app. Along with it comes the Devise authentication. I want to set-up devise :confirmable, and subsequently connect via google and facebook. I tried to set up the file config/initializers/devise.rb for devise :confirmable but changing any config in it doesn't seem to affect my rails app on my local development server. Does this config file provide very limited functionality? Do I need to create a Spree.user_class as specified in this [guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/authentication.html)?

I am able to send mails and see them using the mailcatcher gem. But no mail is being sent when I am creating a new user.

Please advice.

**EDIT**

I have created a custom Spree.user_class following the guide and added `:confirmable` to it but still I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per Ryan's suggestion in this [mailinglist post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spree-user/devise/spree-user/CoP63zIfI_g/DJM6TAqu4YUJ), the best way to implement `Devise :confirmable` is to fork [spree_auth_devise](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise) and make the changes. Sadly it appears no one has done this as yet, or atleast I couldn't find it on github.

Extending the above for Login via google or facebook, etc, is possible but a better way would be to use [spree_social](https://github.com/spree/spree_social). Keep in mind that spree_social is still in beta.